# how to separate files in git branches

Tags: git

So I have 2 branches, master and let's say hotfix

So when I checkout to the hotfix branch and create some file there and then checkout back to the master, I still can see that file in the directory, even though it's a different branch and I wonder if there's a way to separate files from those two directories, so when I checkout to the hotfix branch, that file is present and when I checkout to the master, that file shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file isn't changed by git when you change branch *unless* git knows it.

What you forgot is to add, then commit the file before you came back to master. When you do it, the file *is* removed when you change branch to master, and restored when you change again to the hotfix branch.

Comment: yep, my mistake, thank you very much. I'll accept the answer in 10 mins